# AWSAppSync AWS defined scalar types - definitions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync

The [AppSync docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/scalars.html) 
 describe some extended scalar types, e.g., AWSDateTime, but don't tell me the actual type definitions so I can use in my typescript client (an ionic app). I don't see the types anywhere in the [aws-sdk-js](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js) or the [aws-appsync](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-js) packages - where would I find the definitions or some usage examples for typescript (in my client or lambda functions)?

Answer (score 1):

The appsync doc that you linked does tell you the type.
For example, for `AWSDateTime`:

> The AWSDateTime scalar type represents a valid extended **ISO 8601** DateTime **string**. In other words, this scalar type accepts datetime strings of the form YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sssZ. The field after the seconds field is a nanoseconds field. It can accept between 1 and 9 digits. The seconds and nanoseconds fields are optional (the seconds field must be specified if the nanoseconds field is to be used). The time zone offset is compulsory for this scalar. The time zone offset must either be Z (representing the UTC time zone) or be in the format ±hh:mm:ss. The seconds field in the timezone offset will be considered valid even though it is not part of the ISO 8601 standard.

Comment: Thanks - the narrative description is what I'm using to guide me. But, what I'm looking for its the formal definition, whatever AWS is going to use as validation. I want to do validation in the client (and, for that matter, in the IDE while developing).

Comment: The `validation` would be that it follows the valid extended ISO 8601 DateTime. I encourage you to try out a few examples in the AppSync console, I think that'll help you understand more

Comment: it's not that I don't understand the formats, I can work that out. But I'm looking for the actual type definitions, for typescript. I want to declare typescript variables for those fields and validate the content at runtime (and in my IDE for constants) ... right now all I can do is tell the compiler and runtime "it's a string" and that won't catch errors very well.

Comment: @Wayne AppSync does the coercing and parsing of the ISO 8601 DateTime string on the server, so you can safely assume the data coming back is in the right format. If the value is not a valid ISO 8601 DateTime string, AppSync doesn't allow processing of that field. Now regarding validations on the client, you can find and use Regex to validate this value before passing this in the mutations.

Comment: That's what I'm looking for - the regexes or typescript type definitions to validate *all* the AWS extended types (not just AWSDateTime,  that's only an example).  I want to check this stuff on the client or in the lambda and get hinting in the IDE.